# Reverse Binary Digits

Tags: binary, reverse

I am looking for help with a way to reverse a string of binary digits in java. I don't need a conversion, just a way to reverse the input. For example:

Input: 10101010 -> Output: 01010101

Input: 11001100 -> Output: 00110011

Input: 1011110  -> Output: 0111101

Comment: Have you made any attempt so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String stringReverse(String string) {
  String reversed = "";
  for(int i = string.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversed += string.charAt(i);
  }
  return reversed;
}
```

[Citation](https://www.codepuppet.com/2013/03/24/reversing-a-string-in-java-in-place/)
--Study the above method and then see if you can do it in place. It's just looping through the string from the back.

Comment: I have this written up and I also need a way to enter in a string of digits, where would that go? i have a scanner and input statement above the "string reversed" line. do i need to specify anything in the string reversed quotes?

Comment: Suggest you use the above function to process your input. Get your input into a type string variable (myOldString for example) and then call string myRevString = stringReverse(MyOldString);

Answer (score 0):

I found this on another website and this worked perfectly and it is simple and very easy to understand.

String reverse = new StringBuffer(word).reverse().toString();